# Is it possible to make mouse pointer bigger/enlarged when shaked (like in Mac OS), but in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mac, mouse, mouse-cursor

It is very convenient to find a mouse pointer in mac OS as shaking of the mouse enlarges the pointer for a couple of seconds. I hope we can do the same for windows too. Can we?

I googled a lot but no luck!

Comment: There's an option in Windows to have it visually locate the mouse when you hit CTRL, have you tried that?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 well thanks friend. This will do. Just activated that from my mouse setting. :D

Answer (score 5):

BigMouse will do the trick... http://spinalcode.co.uk/2018/11/06/windows-shake-to-find-cursor/

Just give the mouse a good shake and a giant cursor will show where your mouse is. With the added bonus of tracking how many miles your mouse has moved!

Comment: if you promote a product or service, you should disclose your affiliation with it!

Comment: @spinal, Great work here. However, I found this to be very resistant to mouse movements. I need to move the pointer by a lot for the big trigger to happen.

Comment: Hi Spinal, great piece of code! unfortunately it does not survive computer sleep, need restart to work again

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't do anything on my Windows 10 20H2. The icon appears in the systray, but the cursor doesn't grow no matter how long I shake the mouse.

Comment: the site is down, I find it on wayback machine - https://web.archive.org/web/20210514163235/http://spinalcode.co.uk/2018/11/06/windows-shake-to-find-cursor/

Answer (score 4):

Another utility I found called Shake Mouse To Locate: https://github.com/nicolasdejong/ShakeMouseToLocate. Based on the BigMouse from @spinal mentioned in other answer. Little bit richer than BigMouse and it survives computer sleep!

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

There is [Waggle my mouse](https://gumroad.com/l/zCMp) it is paid thou. But cheap !

And then there is the old... "Click CTRL to show your mouse option"

You can see it in Additional mouse options on Windows 10.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKT63.png)

Comment: I've just tried "Waggle my mouse" but unfortunately found it to be buggy - the huge rainbow circle it makes often gets stuck behind windows and doesn't behave well with multiple monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [my own program](https://gist.github.com/jdhenckel/ecb07bb713a4a6b7c0b4ee01e3fda4b8) to do this. The program waits for the mouse to be idle and then moves it to a HOME location (that you set when you start the program).

This has two benefits. First, it is less likely that you'll lose your mouse (because it returns to the well known location).  Second, if you are editing a document, then the mouse will move out of the way, and not obscure your text.

Answer (score 0):

For that matter, Microsoft has their own addons in form of PowerToys. It will not enlarge/zoom the cursor on shake but it can highlight it instead.. plus plenty of other Windows lifehacks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/